# Change file ownership by being a sudoer

Tags: linux, file-ownership, superuser

let's say that we have this situation :

```
-rwxrwx-w- 1 user1 mygroup  0 Sep 12 16:53 testfile
```

Can a sudoer change this file ownership ? does he have to be a sudoer on command chown or on file ?

Comment: i upvoted it , cause what you said was true but wasn't helpful with my problem

Answer (score 2):

I missed the point that [`the ownership of any file in the system may only be altered by a super-user`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chown).

The 2nd set of rwx shows that any user who is a member of `mygroup` can read, write and execute this file.

So, if the user `user2` is a super-user (present in sudoers and have sufficient permissions), he can make the necessary changes. If not, then he / she can't modify the ownership!

Comment: just tried it doesn't work, because of the need to use chown as a sudoer , is there any possibility to change file ownership without being a sudoer

Comment: @llyasse - Sorry, I've made the edit. The other user can only change the ownership if he is a super-user. Please check the Wikipedia link too.

Comment: yeaah exactly ,  but the doc also shows that a file owner can run chown without sudo thing that i couldn't get to work .

Comment: @llyasse - Which documentation are your referring to? I didn't find any for getting the clarification!

Comment: sorry it's in frensh ,
The command chown( ch ange own er , change the owner) allows you to change the owner of the file. Only the superuser or current owner of a file can use chown. The command is used as follows ==> https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/permissions

Comment: @llyasse - I tranlsated into English; the content is similar to what is mentioned in Wikipedia.

Comment: yes i'm talking about the owner part , they say if the user is file owner he can change ownership but when i run chown without sudo it doesn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154256/discussion-between-am-i-helpful-and-ilyasse).